# C language program for lottery assignment with .exe error showing up

Tags: c

Hey guys so I was writing this program for a class, the assignment I posted below as well as my program. I compiled my program and there seems to be no problem, however when I run the .exe version of my program it crashes after the user input and I have no clue how to fix this problem. If anyone could help me out that would be awesome, thanks!!! This is for the c language

Directions
Suppose you want to develop a program to play lottery. The program randomly generates a Lottery of a two-digit number, prompts the user to enter a two-digit number, and determines whether the user wins according to the following rule:
1.  If the user matches the lottery in exact order , the awards is $10,000.
2.  If the user input matches the lottery, the awards is $3,000.
3.  If one digit in the user input matches a digit in the lottery, the awards is $1,000.

My program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void dowork(int num, int *d1, int *d2);

int main()
 {

    int loto,d1l,d2l,num,d1,d2,reward;

    printf("Enter 2 digit number:\n");

 while(scanf("%d",&num != EOF)) 
    {

        loto=rand()%( 100 - 10 ) + 10;

        dowork(num,&d1,&d2);

        dowork(loto,&d1l,&d2l);

            if
                ((d1==d1l)&&(d2==d2l))

                printf(" You have won 10,000$ \n",reward);

            else if 
                ((d1==d2l)&&(d2==d1l))
                printf(" You have won 3,000$ \n",reward);

            else if
                ((d1==d1l) || (d1==d2l) || (d2==d1l) || (d2==d2l))
                printf(" You have won 1,000$ \n",reward);

    }

    return 0;
}   

void dowork(int num, int *d1, int *d2)

{

   *d1 = num /10;
   *d2 = num %10;

}
```

Comment: *"crashes after the user input"*... After what input exactly?  What kind of crash, exactly?  (Seg Fault?  Hangs? Blue Screen of Death?)

Answer (score 2):

```
 while(scanf("%d",&num != EOF))
```

This looks like misplaced parentheses -- it might compile, but almost certainly isn't
what you intended.  Try this instead:

```
 while(scanf("%d",&num) == 1)
```

`scanf` returns the number of fields successfully converted, so for your problem
you need to compare the return value to 1, instead of EOF.

Comment: Thanks that really helped, I'm still having some difficulty with response time but otherwise everything is still working. Really appreciate the help from you guys even though I am a new member!

Comment: When I run the program, it works for one second very quickly and then another second it doesn't work at all, I'm not exactly sure why, but I'm playing around with it to see what's happening, maybe I screwed up in the code.